# Only allow one property to have a given value if another property has another given value

Tags: python, cerberus

I want to do something fairly simple. I've browsed through the questions already asked here but couldn't find an answer to my specific issue. I've played around with `excludes` and `allowed` and `dependencies`, to no avail. Can someone please put me on the right track?

Here's what I'm trying to do:

I have data that looks like `{"field1": 1, "field2": true}`. I want to allow `field2` to be `true` only if `field1` is equal to `1`.

Here are a few examples:

*Not allowed:*

1. `{"field1": 2, "field2" true}`

*Allowed:*

1. `{"field1": 2, "field2" false}`
2. `{"field1": 1, "field2": true}`

I've tried the following but this doesn't catch the example that is not allowed from above.

```
'field1': {
        'type': 'integer',
        'default': 1,
},
'field2': {
        'type': 'boolean',
        'default': False,
        'oneof': [{'excludes': 'field1', 'allowed': [1]}, {'allowed': [True]}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define *allowed* key as such: `allowed = True if (d['field1'] == 1 and d['field2']) or (d['field1'] != 1 and not d['field2']) else False`.

Comment: this feels like cheating my way out of understanding how cerberus really works. i would prefer to find a way to write it without using python code in the middle of the validation config.

Comment: Well it's pure python, I am not familiar with cerberus...